# Solve the pair of simultaneous equations for $x$ and $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$Px + (1-q)y = R$ and $qx + (1-p)y = S$
$x$ and $y$ are the unknowns.

I've solved the first equation for $y$ such that

$y = (R - px)/(1-q)$

I've substituted this in place of $y$ the second equation so that,

$qx + (1-p)(R-px)/(1-q) = S$

I'm not able to simplify it further. Please help!

Comment: You should state which are the unknowns.

Comment: Why don't you use Cramer ? This is a quite ordinary system.

Comment: it it $$px+(1-q)y=R,qx+(1-p)y=S$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  yes

Answer (score 2):

Hint: With $$y=\frac{R-px}{1-q}$$ for $$q\neq 1$$ we get the equation
$$qx+\frac{(1-p)(R-px)}{1-q}=S$$
Can you proceed?
$$x=-\frac{-p R+q S+R-S}{p^2-p-q^2+q}$$
$$y=-\frac{q R-p S}{-p^2+p+q^2-q}$$
Multiplying out we get
$$q(1-q)x-p(1-p)x=S(1-q)-(1-p)R$$

Comment: I'm stuck exactly here, I'm not able to simplify it further.

Comment: Are you required to?  That looks like a perfectly good answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides of $px+(1-q)y=R$ by $q$ to get $pqx+q(1-q)y=qR$

Multiply both sides of $qx+(1-p)y=S$ by $p$ to get $pqx+p(1-p)y=pS$

Subtract the two equations to get $q(1-q)y-p(1-p)y =qR-pS$

Expand the brackets: $[q(1-q)-p(1-p)]y =qR-pS$

$y =\frac {qR-pS}{q(1-q)-p(1-p)}$

Answer (score 0):

Express $y$ in both:
$$y=\frac{S-qx}{1-p} \quad \text{and} \quad y=\frac{R-px}{1-q}\Rightarrow\\
S(1-q)-q(1-q)x=R(1-p)-p(1-p)x \Rightarrow \\
x=\frac{R(1-p)-S(1-q)}{p(1-p)-q(1-q)}$$
Substituting into $y$:
$$y=\frac{S-qx}{1-p}=\frac{S-q\cdot \frac{R(1-p)-S(1-q)}{p(1-p)-q(1-q)}}{1-p}=\frac{Sp(1-p)-q(1-p)R}{(1-p)(p(1-p)-q(1-q))}=\frac{Sp-Rq}{p(1-p)-q(1-q)}.$$
Note: It is assumed $p,q\ne 1$, which is rather a trivial case.